# oracle database sync using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I would greatly appreciate if someone could share if it is possible to do a near real time oracle database sync application using spring integration. Its a lightweight requirement where only certain data fields across couple of tables to be copied over as soon as they change in source database. Any thoughts around what architecture can be used would greatly help. Also if any Oracle utility that can be leveraged along with SI?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the `Oracle Trigger` is for you. When the main data is changed you should use a trigger to move those changes to another table at the same DB.

From SI you should use `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` to read and remove data from that `sync` table. Within the same transaction you have to use `<int-jdbc:outboud-channel-adapter>` to move the data to another DB.

The main feature here should be a `XA` transaction, because you use two DBs and what is good they both are Oracle.

Of course you can try to use the [1PC effort](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html), but there will be need more work to do.

Comment: Thanks Artem, that is certainly an option but i was exploring something even based. I was trying to see if there is any built in support in SI that can directly plug into an Oracle DB and listen to any oracle specific mechanism of data change events, something on those lines. I can probably have a trigger inside Oracle that sends out a message to a message broker, but that adds a big overhead to put that trigger on each table and code for each table columns etc.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that there is any Java tools on matter at all... You can try to look into the Oracle AQ (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm), but there is really nothing from SI prespective: it just relies on raw JDBC. However you can try to use a JMS bridge for AQ.